# My site shutdown because I used remove action directly in function.php theme

Tags: wordpress

I used `remove_action` directly in my function.php child theme, and my site shutdown, How can I restore my site?

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash', 10 );
```

Comment: try to remove the code that you added within function.php

Comment: I already did it but it didn't work

Comment: Remove the code that you added within function.php using FTP(filezilla).

Comment: do you get some php error?

Comment: The site is experiencing technical difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

Please edit your wp-config.php file and change define('WP_DEBUG', false) to define('WP_DEBUG', true);

The wp-config.php file should present in the Wordpress root directory.

This will display the exact error and then you can fix the PHP error.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go slowly with the last changes and found that something with a plugin was also causing the error. Maybe with the function that I put in the functions.php file in my child theme caused the plugin to break.